# Faster Django filter querying for very large database

Tags: django, django-queryset, large-data

I am creating a geospatial web app and have a very large database, at the moment it is 7.5 million entries long and will be almost 60 million entries long by the time all the data is uploaded. I want to display all the points from a certain date and am simply using `Model.objects.filter(datetime__date=requested_date)` at the moment. Each date request takes ~8s to load. How can I filter in a more efficient way? If there are better ways to store geospatial data points, I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: Add a `db_index=True` on your `datetime` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That does make it very slightly faster I think, but I'm not sure. I read something about `db_index=True` working the best on fields where values don't repeat very often, which isn't true in my case. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: what if you filter with `.filter(datetime__range=(requested_date, requested_date + timedelta(days=1)))`?